# How is "&" used to print the integer value of a process exit code?

Tags: c, linux, printf, fork, wait

I was looking at a didactical example, and I saw that my professor used this syntax to print the exit value of a child process:

```
wait(&value);
printf("last two bytes of value are %d - %d\n",(value>>8)&255,value&255);
```

The "value" variable is defined as an int, and the wait() is used by the parent to wait the child process generated through a "fork()". The child can be terminated by a signal or it terminates by itself after a fixed amount of time.
From what I've understood, since the variable "value" is an int it has 4 bytes, but the exit code of a "exit(int)" is written in just one of the four bytes. If the process is not terminated by an exit(), but instead from a signal, in another of those four bytes I recive the code of that signal.
So I guess that the fact that I have "(value>>8)" is due to this use of the bytes, but what I don't understand is why I use the syntax with "&255" to print those values.

Comment: see [arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there is some bit operations are going on:

Imagine you have 32 bit integer:

0101 0101 1011 0101 1101 1010 1111 1101

1: `(value>>8)&255` this will perform two operations: shift to the right 8 times, then "and" operation. After shift:

0000 0000 0101 0101 1011 0101 1101 1010

After "and" :

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1101 1010.

This is the value of the first eight bits on the final result.

2. `value&255`: this will perform "and" again, and you have:

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1101

This is the last 8 bits of the result.

**TL:DR**

`value&255` Will zero out the first 24 bits of the 32 bit value.

Answer (score 1):

Number 255 is represented as `11111111` in binary and `FF` in hexadecimal. Bitwise anding with this number will leave only only 8 lowest bits. Higher bits would be zeroed.

This operation is likely unnecessary as manual for `wait()` tells:

```
SYNOPSIS
       void exit(int status);
DESCRIPTION
       The exit() function causes normal process termination and
       the value of status & 0xFF is returned to the parent (see wait(2)).
```

Comment: The operation is necessary as the child process could end not due to the normal ```exit()``` but due to the signal. I assume the professor used these least bytes to show how ```wstatus``` is used in macros like ( WEXITSTATUS)[https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html]

Answer (score 0):

`some_int & 255` (as well as `some_int & 0xFF` for which it is even more obvious) means just "take least byte and zero everything else". So the code just prints out byte 1 and byte 0 of the process status code.

I don't get why does your professor even bother with the thing though.
If you need the return code of a child process you should use the standard WEXITSTATUS() macro and other standard macros for other statuses instead.
If you are using Linux then `man 3 wait` should give you complete description for of all of the available macros if you ever need them.